# Make a list of the numbers from one to one million and then use a for loop to print the numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an exercise from a book called *Python Crash Course* by Eric Matthes. I tried this as a possible solution:

```
millions= list(range(1,1000001))
for million in range:

    print(million)
```

However, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "expendable_exerciseloop.py", line 5, in 
>       for million in range: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python for range example", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 5):

`range` is a generator. You should avoid building a memory-hogging list of a million items if you don't actually need to index the items. For the purpose of iterating over the million items generated by `range`, you can simply use a `for` loop to iterate over the generator:

```
for i in range(1, 1000001):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do

```
millions= range(1,1000001)
for million in millions:
    print(million)
```

Range will already generate the list as you go, so no need to try to make it a list.

What really happens under the hood is that range() generates a value every time you ask for one. All the values are never stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this:

```
list=np.arange(1,1000001,1).tolist()
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Edited so you actually use a list.

`np.arange(a,b,c)` creates an array that goes from a to b-1 on c-step intervals and then I turn it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print every number of your list you have to specified the list itself as a range like the example below:

```
millions = list(range(1, 1_000_001))
for number in millions:
    print(million)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting as well and reading the same book. If it's exercise 4-4. One Million, this is what I put down:

```
numbers = [value for value in range(1,1000001)]
print(numbers)
```

Not sure if it's good list comprehension, but it made sense to me at the time.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that `range` is a function, and not a iterable. Thus it requires  arguments. Check out this material for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Comment: While useful, your response, as is, is best left as a Comment to the OP's question, as it does not indicate how their code would be modified to make it work. Please `edit` to add the code necessary to implement your suggestion. Or consider deleting, to add it as a Comment. Answers on SO generally need to include code to be considered a "compete" Answer. On the plus side, you already included a great explanation, and a source link, which is also a distinguishing element of Answers from Comments/suggestions. Self-contained, Complete answers, with clear explanations, are most likely to be upvoted

Answer (score -2):

```
millions= list(range(1,1000001))


for million in range(1,1000001):

    print(million)
```

Comment: Providing just code is acceptable, but answers are far more useful (and tend to be recognized by the community as such) when they additionally provide an explanation of _why_ it addresses the original problem, and why it might be preferable over other existing answers.

Comment: More importantly, though, this is basically  an exact repeat of an answer provided a year ago. Please be sure to review other answers before submitting your own.

Comment: Code-only (& link-only) responses are best left as Comments, Not Answers. While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not  a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, self-contained, complete Answers are more likely to be upvoted, and are some strengths the SO platform has, differentiating it from forums. You can `edit` to add an explanation, & to supplement your reasoning with source documentation.

Comment: One strength of the SO platform relies on users upvoting useful Answers, and Comments. Duplicating Answers that already exist, on the other hand, degrades the usefulness of this platform, which differs from traditional forums. As this post does not add anything new or useful, it is likely to be down-voted, and may even be subject to deletion. Upvoting useful responses is free, generous, rewarding, and helps users find the best solutions for their use cases. No need to reinvent the wheel, either :-)